# SET statement always runs regardless of IF ELSE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, set, if-statement

I'm losing my sanity over this SQL code. The below IF ELSE statement functions correctly when testing with simple PRINT statement, i.e. the table does not exist so it prints 'FALSE'. But when I uncomment the SET statement and execute, it tries to run the SET statement, and naturally gives and error since the table does not exist.

```
DECLARE @zeus_calls310_counter int;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [zeus].tpza.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'calls_310')
BEGIN
    --SET @zeus_calls310_counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [zeus].[tpza].[dbo].[calls_310]);
    PRINT 'TRUE'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'FALSE';
END
```

Comment: What brand of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Your title indicates where your understanding goes wrong. In the case where the table does not exist, it is not that the `SET` statement **runs** and gives an error; it is that when the statement is **parsed** there is an error.

Whenever you run some SQL, the server first **parses** the statement, and then, if parsing succeeds, **runs** it. So you cannot have bare SQL that depends on the existence of tables! Your `SET` statement will be **parsed** whether or not the table exists - so when it doesn't, parsing fails.

One solution to this is to wrap those statements that depend on objects that may or may not exist within `EXEC`. However, in this case you want to populate a variable with the result of a query on that table, and inside an `EXEC` that variable will not be in scope. So we'd need more detail on what you're doing to do with `@zeus_calls310_counter` - if it's going to be used soon after, perhaps you could wrap the whole thing, including its declaration, in an `EXEC`.

Answer (score 2):

@AAkashM is on the right track.

If you use [EXEC sp_executesql](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499/en) you can also specify OUTPUT parameters, which in your case would contain the result of the `SELECT COUNT` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @zeus_calls310_counter int;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [zeus].tpza.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'calls_310')
BEGIN
    SET @zeus_calls310_counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [zeus].[tpza].[calls_310]);
    PRINT 'TRUE'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'FALSE';
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this for checking if table exists

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[zeus].[table_name]', N'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
    --
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --
END
```